# iOS app flashing and closing on remote debug from Visual Studio

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm a beginner in iOS development in Visual Studio 2013 through Xamarin.
I made a test app and tried to debug it on the MacBook Pro through LAN remote debugging.
As soon as I debug, the app starts shows launch screen and after 1 second it close, this happens several times and then the app stops.
I'm using xamarin 6.1.4.1 on both machines.
It shows the error : An error occurred while executing the mtouch.
What should I do now??

Comment: Are you aware of [Visual Studio For Mac?](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)  It looks like it may support the types of things you may be doing...

Comment: Yup, I tried both. Then I made a clean install of Xamarin Studio on my Mac and then everything started working fine. It seems like and error in installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through every things, I re-installed Xamarin Studio by using Xamarin Installer rather than installing individual components. Seems like Xamarin Installer makes some more changes in system other than installing components.